# Setting Image on an Image view after launching camera

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I'm not able to set the image taken by the camera on an Imageview. I have added permission too  ! Here is the piece of code I'm using : 
    B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
    B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
@Override           
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}
});

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
        {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]
                            {
                                Media.DATA, 
                                Media.DATE_ADDED, 
                                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
                            }, 
                            Media.DATE_ADDED, 
                            null, 
                            "date_added ASC"
            );
if (data != null)
            {
                if (data.hasExtra("data"))
                {
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                   // mImageView.postInvalidate();
                }
```

Please Help !!

Comment: DO I have to do something with Layout ? I have a linear layout and inside it I have this image view .

Answer (score 0):

You should move your cursor to first element with a Cursor.moveToFirst() (If exists!)